# Should encrypted data base64 encoded to store it in a database?

Tags: security, encryption, base64, rsa, rijndael

Should I first encode my encrypted text with base64 to store it in a database? It will be larger when I encode it but is better or faster to decrypt it?
(Especially for Rijndael and RSA encrypted data.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to encode your ciphertext using base64 encoding. You should encode your ciphertext only if your field just accepts text values. Speed is normally not an issue as cryptographic algorithms are much slower than the conversion from or to base64.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly than you do not need to encode with base64 before storing it in the database. If you use a proper database than you can just store the raw bytes. Base64 is good for transferring binary data over text-only media but, it also enlarges data by roughly 33%. It would not make it faster because you actually need to do two steps now: decode and than decrypt, instead of decrypting it immediately.